# .show() not working after the class has been hidden()

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm trying to show something triggered by a click event after the element has been hidden.  I can't for the life of me figure out why the .show() is not working.  I've tried everything I can think of.  What I have right now is the following:

```
function hideArrows(index){
  var hiddenId = parseInt($(".queueListDiv .track").first().attr("id"), 10);
  console.log("hiddenId = " + hiddenId + currentIndex)
    if(index == hiddenId){
      console.log("true son")
      $("#" + hiddenId + " .soundMove").hide();
      $("#" + (hiddenId + 1) + " .fa-arrow-up").hide();
    } 
}

function showArrows(){
  $(".queueListDiv .track").each(function(){
    var otherId = parseInt($(this).attr("id"))
    if (otherId > 1){
      $(this).attr(".queueListDiv .track .soundMove .fa-arrow-up").show()
    }
  })
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="queueList" class="queueListDiv col-md-4">
      <div class='track' id='this is some number'>
        <div class="soundMove">
          <i class="moveUp fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
          <i class="moveDown fa fa-arrow-down"></i> 
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The callback for `showArrows` is after the callback for the `hideArrows` callback in a click event.

Comment: The `.attr()` function returns the value of an attribute by name when you pass it one parameter as you have. Because the element certainly doesn't have an attribute with that name (the selector string), it's going to return `undefined`. You're probably getting an error in the console.

Comment: That's what I originally thought...how can I tell it to show a specific class to $(this)?

Comment: Also, you're trying to parse the "id" of the "track" element as an integer, but its "id" value is "test".

Comment: You're probably thinking of `.find()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: Also if the "soundMove" `<div>` has been hidden, then no matter what you do to things inside it they will not be shown.

Comment: Try not using number for `id`.

Comment: I just edited it.  The id's are integers, but I just had that for testing purposes.  The id's in the code are integers.  The soundMove div isn't hidden on the one i'm trying to show.  Only the `.fa-arrow-up`.

Comment: @ElliottMcNary I just want you to try my answer. I have a small hunch that this might be causing becoz of the ID as number. Let me know if it doesn't work. I have to remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but **will** work. So I am posting it as an answer. Let the OP check and if it works, then let it be, else I will delete this one.

It is a good practise to have `id` not start with numbers or made up of numbers fully. So try adding a bit of character in the front.

Your HTML must be like:

```
<div id="queueList" class="queueListDiv col-md-4">
  <div class='track' id='track-{number}'>
    <div class="soundMove">
      <i class="moveUp fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
      <i class="moveDown fa fa-arrow-down"></i> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And your jQuery code can be:

```js
function hideArrows(index){
  var hiddenId = parseInt($(".queueListDiv .track").first().attr("id"), 10);
  console.log("hiddenId = " + hiddenId + currentIndex)
  if(index == hiddenId){
    console.log("true son")
    $("#track-" + hiddenId + " .soundMove").hide();
    $("#track-" + (hiddenId + 1) + " .fa-arrow-up").hide();
  } 
}

function showArrows(){
  $(".queueListDiv .track").each(function(){
    var otherId = parseInt($(this).attr("id").replace("track-", ""))
    if (otherId > 1){
      $(this).attr(".queueListDiv .track .soundMove .fa-arrow-up").show()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  Changing the Id's would have taken a lot of refactoring around the app so I was able to find a workaround as per my above solution.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottMcNary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped...I was able to figure it out.  I had realized that I actually needed to use the hiddenId variable in my condition, so I instead just wrote one function which looks like the below:

```
function hideOrShowArrows(index){
  var hiddenId = parseInt($(".queueListDiv .track").first().attr("id"), 10);
  console.log("hiddenId = " + hiddenId + currentIndex)
    if(index == hiddenId){
      console.log("true son")
      $("#" + hiddenId + " .soundMove").hide();
      $("#" + (hiddenId + 1) + " .fa-arrow-up").hide();
    } 
  $(".queueListDiv .track").each(function(){
    var otherId = parseInt($(this).attr("id"))
    if (otherId > (hiddenId + 1)){
      $("#" + otherId + " .fa-arrow-up").show()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Aha.. I found out your issue just now! LoL.